# Indexing steps in a web crawler

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am writing a web crawler (focused web crawler) where:
input : seedsURL
output: bigger seedsURL

```
  def crawl(seedURL, pageslimit):
      crawling code ...

      return list of urls crawled
```

Now I need to index and store the data to facilitate fast and accurate information retrieval(search engine).

1. My crawler returns a list of the URLs, how can I pass them to indexing phase? Should I download the content of each page in a text file?
2. Are there some tools or library to do the indexing step? Or has it to be done manually?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) for this job of web crawling. I'm going to give you an example of how it can be used and how your web index should be. Any other question, go check the site out!

Using the XPath expression provided by Scrapy, you can extract the resources you want including the whole file.

For example: `<h1>Darwin - The Evolution Of An Exhibition</h1>`

The XPath expression: `//h1/text()`

Why do this? With the h1 tag, you can make it into a key in the **dictionary**. By having a dictionary, you can access the files easier. Like so:

```
web_index = {
    'Darwin': 'example.html',
    'Evolution': 'example.html'
}
```

It's best for the web index to be in a dictionary as it is a **key-value pair** where you can easily 'search' from, not like in a list where you rely on their index.

Comment: I used scrapy to extraxt data from specific sites. but in other module  I need to crawl a part of web (focused crawler) to search relevant information. I build one that return a list of urls, but indexing the results to do search in database after isn't clear for me.